# Google Analytics - report with unrelated dimensions?

Tags: google-analytics, goal-tracking

It is possible to include two unrelated dimensions in a report? For example I would like to do:

```
<Filter: completed goal 1>
<(AND) Filter: referral traffic>

                              Goal completions        Goal value
Referral source 1        
  - Goal URL 1
  - Goal URL 2
  - Goal URL 3
Referral source 1
  - Goal URL 4
Referral source 1
  - Goal URL 5
Referral source 1
  - Goal URL 6
```